# Appearance of the Dirac delta operator in Laplace's work

Tags: mathematics

I found a reference to the following article ;

O B Sheynin, The appearance of Dirac's delta functions in the works of P S Laplace (Russian), Istor.-Mat. Issled. Vyp. 20 (1975), 303-308, 381.

I don't have access to this nor can I read in Russian. Can anyone summarize this paper? I'm fairly familiar with the Laplace and other integral transforms, so a brief statement of and explanation of any nonstandard notation in the central formula or formulas as presented by Laplace would probably suffice.

Comment: I would glad to summarize but I do not have the paper.

Comment: @Alexander Eremenko, If I locate it, I'll send you a link. Thanks for the offer.

Comment: DJVU copy of the volume can be downloaded from [Историко-математические исследования](http://pyrkov-professor.ru/Default.aspx?tabid=195&articleid=59&dnnprintmode=true&mid=629&SkinSrc=[G]Skins%2F_default%2FNo+Skin&ContainerSrc=[G]Containers%2F_default%2FNo+Container).

Comment: According to the author, Laplace in a 1893 memoir "*in fact introduces Dirac's delta-function, or more precisely, one of its interpretations, - the sequence of funtions (1) for $a\to\infty$*". The sequence (1) is $\frac1{2a}\ln\frac{a}{|x|}$ from one of his early attempts to find the error curve. Of course, if this counts as "in fact introducing" the delta function then Fourier, Poisson, Fejer, Gauss, etc., "in fact introduced" it too.

Comment: @Conifold, great! Thanks. Looks like a nascent delta to me of the type Zemanian discusses. As far as I know, Heaviside was the first to write down an expression in his unique style of the Dirac delta as $e^{tD_x} 1 := e^{tD_x} \; H(x) = \delta(x-t)$.

Comment: @Conifold, perhaps you want to re-do your comment to correct '1893' to '1793'?

Comment: I suppose Laplace surmised that from looking at the limit of the Euler integral for the gamma function $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{b-1}}{(b-1)!} \; e^{-xt} \; dx = 1/t^{b}$ as $b$ tends to $0^{+}$.

Comment: Laplace was more conceptual about deriving the error curve. Stahl discusses his considerations in [The Evolution of the Normal Distribution, pp. 103-4](https://www.maa.org/programs/maa-awards/writing-awards/the-evolution-of-the-normal-distribution). It was his second try, the first one, $\frac{m}2e^{-m|x|}$, dates back to 1774.

Comment: If he didn't demonstrate a sifting property in the limit, I wouldn't claim he discovered a nascent delta operator.

Comment: He wouldn't have discovered it even if he did. Authors who wrote on various kernels (Cauchy, Dirichlet, Fejer, etc.) in the context of inverting Fourier series or transforms often proved something equivalent. But they did not conceive of any kind of limit object capable of having properties, which is what Dirac's discovery (or invention) was. Heaviside was the first to have something like that, at least as a symbolic image in his operational calculus.

Comment: Yes, but the Bargmann-Segal, or Weierstrass-Gauss, transform gives the sifting property for the heat kernel as a nascent delta function as time tends to zero. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40268/why-is-the-gaussian-so-pervasive-in-mathematics/383402#383402. Same for the Poisson kernel as in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/127601/does-the-derivative-of-log-have-a-dirac-delta-term/364456#364456, so I'm inclined to give credit to those who constructed integral transform solns. to problems in potential theory or heat flow credit for the first nascent deltas.

Comment: Heaviside and Dirac, following Heaviside, had the temerity to relate their delta operators to the derivative of a discontinuous function. That, to me, is their unique contribution--a touch of wizardry. (And the inspiration for the rigorous foundations of generalized functions.)